# How to read response in server after sending an alert to specific user in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm new to Socket.io. Here is my problem.
I want to get the real time location of Android device. So I created a simple app to get current GPS location. And Node.js server and also Angular Admin panel.

Here is my Node.js server code.

```
//Some import statements are missing here. Not added.
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Creating the socket connection.
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join', function (data) {
        socket.join(data.id); 
    });
});

module.exports = function (app, express) {
    var api = express.Router();

    api.post('/device_location/:child_id', function (req, res) {
        var child_id = req.body.child_id;
        io.sockets.in(child_id).emit('new_msg', {msg: 'gps_data'}); //Sending request to registered android device.
        var gps_location = ""; //Here i want to take GPS data from android client.
        res.json({ type: "success", code: 200, data: gps_location }); //Then i can send the response to anyone who need that.
    });

    return api;
};
```

If this is not clear, please check this gist : https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/123080fa5427c38c37f36afdac10be7c

First I created the socket connection. Then Android client can connect to it with unique user ID.

Then I'm sending the request to get GPS data when admin press the button from the Administration button.

> io.sockets.in(child_id).emit('new_msg', {msg: 'gps_data'});

Here, `child_id`  is the ID of android application.
Then I want to get the response from Android app and read it in server.
After reading that, I can send that to anyone asking for it.

> res.json({ type: "success", code: 200, data: gps_location });

This is the normal Node.js way of sending a response.

How can we get the response to this `var gps_location = "";` variable which we are getting GPS value of specific user.

Please help me on this. Tried many ways, but not good. I just need to read the response from Android client in the server and process it.

Comment: Guys, before down voting this, can you please tell me what's the issue with this ? This is the problem i'm having now. So ? This is the best way i can express that.

Comment: Ignore the downvotes. Your question looks good and StackOverflow is full of stupid silent downvoters that won't help. If you want your server to receive data for Android, then you need your Android app to send it to the server with `socket.emit("gpsdata", data)`, and then receive it on your server with `socket.on("gpsdata", data => { ...... })`

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks. But there are hundreds of users. So I want to read it according to userID. Like i'm sending to specific user, can i read response from specific user ? What if 2 Android users sent GPS data same time ?

Comment: Also you can get child_id using `child_id = req.params.child_id`

Comment: Each socket corresponds to one user.

Comment: @JeremyThille Oh, i got it now. https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/123080fa5427c38c37f36afdac10be7c#file-server-js-L21

Comment: check this. Now it should work like this i think. Or can you update the gist ?

Comment: You mean develop the feature? Sorry no, I don't think so :) I gave you a hint. But move it with `socket.on('join')`. otherwise you'll attach the socket event only after the `post('/device_location/:child_id')` route is reached, that doesn't make sense

Comment: OK, posted a suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to emit your GPS location from Android to your server using something like :

```
socket.emit("gpsdata", data)
```

and then receive it in Node using `socket.on("gpsdata", doSomething)` :

```
io.sockets.on('connection',  socket => {
    socket.on("gpsdata", data => { // Receive data from one socket
        io.sockets.emit('gps_location', { gps_location : data }) // Emit to everyone
    })
});
```

https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy. But when many users going to do this, how we can identify the sender ? Because we have to display the specific sender's location on the map. Please help me

Comment: There's this solution I like : `socket` is an object; like every object in JS, you can extend it, for instance by attaching user data to it : `socket.user = { name : "John", location : [ 1.234, 5.678 ] }`. So each socket will always carry its user's information. You can get the location by doing `socket.user.location`.